# Problems with raid 5

Tags: raid, mdadm

I'm having a problem with an array. It was originally based on 3 identical disks, then I add a new one but something was wrong.
So now I've an inactive raid:

```
root@nas:/home/al# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sda1[4](S) sdd1[1](S) sde1[3](S) sdc1[0](S)
      11720531968 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>
```

```
root@nas:/home/al# mdadm --detail --scan
INACTIVE-ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=nas:0 UUID=dc9e082e:3ceccaca:677044e7:ebe054a1
```

```
root@nas:/home/al# mdadm --assemble --scan -v
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdf1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdf
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdd
mdadm: /dev/sde1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sde
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb5
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sda1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
```

How can I solve without loss data, please?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: I'm using another distro (debian), but I'm also an ubuntu user on other servers.

Answer (score -1):

In some ways I was able to restart the array, but now there is a removed disk and It's reshaping. The problem is that reshaping is quite slow:

```
root@nas:/home/al# mdadm --detail /dev/md0 
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Sep 22 10:30:30 2020
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 5860265984 (5588.79 GiB 6000.91 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2930132992 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Jan 21 14:00:40 2021
             State : clean, degraded, reshaping 
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Reshape Status : 99% complete
     Delta Devices : 1, (3->4)

              Name : nas:0  (local to host nas)
              UUID : 
            Events : 23494

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       -       0        0        2      removed
       4       8        1        3      active sync   /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Seriously you solved but didn't share any additional info?  Ugh!